# Using type of extension parameter to pass as an Generic type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods

I am attempting to write and extension method that takes the type of a this parameter and passes it along to a generically typed method ie

```
public TDestination MethodName<TSource, TDestination>(this TSource obj)
{
      return DestinationClass.DestinationMethod<TSource, TDestination>(obj)
}
```

How can I assume the type of the this parameter as the type of the Destination Method is this possible with defining the TSource when calling the method

Clarification:  I want to create a helper method so that i can directly call MethodName from an object and use a prewritten generic method with 2 types so i want to shorten this to a single destination type and have the method assume the type of the object being passed to the extension method

Usage Example: ie AutoMapper extension example

Original Method Call:

```
  var person = _db.People.Single(q=>q.Id == 5);
  //use automapper directly to map object 
  return Mapper.Map<Person, PersonDisplay>(person);
```

I want to shorten this down to

```
  var person = _db.People.Single(q=>q.Id == 5);

  //use extension method to map 
  return person.MapTo<PersonDisplay>()
```

Want to shorten this to

Comment: Your question is really unclear - I'm afraid I have no idea what you're asking. Please edit it and clarify.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to be able to call `someTSourceObj.MethodName<SomeTDestination>()` and skip having to explicitly declare `TSource` like: `someTSourceObj.MethodName<SomeTSource, SomeTDestination>()`?

Comment: i updated the question with a usage example of what i want to do

Comment: exactly what i want do  @ChrisSinclair

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Generic parameters must be all explicit or all implicit. You cannot get the compiler to infer one yet supply the other. Consequently you will require a different API. Maybe via an intermediate so you have something like:

```
obj.Foo().Bar<AnotherType>();
```

which is possible.